# 'Pronouns in English alone or 'Pronouns alone in English'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> There are roughly a dozen different types of pronouns in English alone.

I think that the author should have used 'alone' after 'pronouns' because, going by the premises, it is clear that the author wanted to emphasize the sheer  strength of a part of speech in English language whereas the sentence, the way it is, would seem to imply that she is comparing the strength of pronouns in English to other pronouns in other languages. Am I right?

Comment: it's fine. It's clear.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the wording as it was written. You could rephrase it (as in the answer), but you don't need to. (In fact, I personally prefer to the original version to the rephrased version—which actually has a subtly *different* meaning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the current position of the word "alone" indicates some kind of comparison between English and other languages.

If the author's intent was to make a contrast between *pronouns* or *types of pronouns* and some other parts of speech, then "alone" would work better in a different location. E.g.:

> In English there are roughly a dozen different types of pronouns
>   alone.

or, maybe:

> There are roughly a dozen different types of pronouns alone in English.

But that last wording sounds a little clumsy to me.